# Scrape a websites's javascript variables using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the real time values of variables of a website using my NodeJS application.

I have tried "cheerio" but it didn't worked. It only returns me the HTML of the target in a string not the runtime values of the variables.

For example the value of "google.authuser" of "www.google.com"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXXDF.png)

Please suggest me a simple solution.
Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for a headless browser (that runs the code in the website) then.

Comment: +1 @Bergi, a [headless browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) will do the job, you can then do something like `.executeScript(...)` and get the value back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the recommendations of the Headless browser.
[Headless Chrome NodeJS API Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) worked for me.

```
async function crawl() {
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('http://www.google.com');

const dataPromise = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        number: google.authuser
    });
});

browser.close();
return dataPromise;}
```

Comment: From [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) doc: "If the function passed to the `page.evaluate` returns a Promise, then `page.evaluate` would wait for the promise to resolve and return its value." So your code can be simplified a bit: `const data = await page.evaluate(() => google.authuser);`